# Literal Arabic Page numbers need default 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... XeLatex

Tags: xetex, page-numbering, arabic

I may have inadvertently insulted my client by using actual Arabic Script page numbering.   Would like it to be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc...  I can not get this to override.  I can get Roman numerals and alphabetical counter for page numbering just not the standard default 'english' or Western page numbering.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[text={70mm,5.5in}, paperwidth=82mm, paperheight=6in, footskip=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[SizeFeatures={Size=17}]
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=.75]{Arial}
\let\XeTeX\undefined
\let\XeLaTeX\undefined
\usepackage[quiet,nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1,locale=mashriq ]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\large
\sloppy
\section{الكتاب 1}
\section{تعريف}


\textbf{ فلا تسمعوا انتم لانبيائكم وعرافيكم وحالميكم وعائفيكم وسحرتكم الذين يكلموكم قائلين لا تخدموا ملك بابل.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The option `numerals=maghrib` gives Western-style digits. But do you want some things, like section numbers, to *not* be Western?

Comment: Thank you that was it.  I thought I tried that from the polyglossia manual.  Guess I tried mashriq twice.  To anyone who reads later, it is an option on \setdefaultlanguage in polyglossia under Arabic in the manual.  Thank you so much Cicada